# Finish playing a sound before continuing with execution

Tags: c#, if-statement, soundplayer

I am trying to make my application play a quick .wav before closing the application, but every time it only plays the .wav and does not exit the application. Here is my code:

```
bool condition = false;

if (condition)
{
    SoundPlayer sndPlayer = new SoundPlayer(Project_Rage_v3._1.Properties.Resources.syl);
    sndPlayer.Play();
}
else
{
    Application.Exit();
}
```

I know if the bool == true it will do the if function and if the bool == false it will do the else function. But if I don't split them up, the program just quits immediately without playing the sound.

How do I have it play the sound then quit, but only quit after the sound is finished playing?

Comment: This appears to be too broad a question because I don't know how to explain program sequence in a way that is generally applicable without taking seventeen pages to cover all the bases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the else block. You're telling the program to play the sound if `condition` is true, and exit if `condition` is false. Put the commands in sequential order and call `PlaySync` instead of `Play` ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer.playsync%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). This will block the rest of the code from executing until the playing is finished.

```
bool condition = false;
if (condition)
{
    SoundPlayer sndPlayer = new SoundPlayer(Project_Rage_v3._1.Properties.Resources.syl);
    sndPlayer.PlaySync();
    Application.Exit();
}
```

Comment: If you want the application to exit only if the condition is `true` the above will work, but if you want the application to exit even if the condition is `false` but only have the sound play if `true`, then you need to move `Application.Exit()` outside the `if` statement.